# Continuity of function $h(t)=\mathbb{E}\text{sin}(tX)$.

Tags: continuity, random-variables, expected-value

Let X be a random variable. If $\mathbb{E}|X|=\infty$, how can we prove that $h(t)=\mathbb{E}\text{sin}(tX)$ is continuous at every $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Dominated convergence?

Comment: @d.k.o. Could you please explain it a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Take any sequence $t_n\to t$. Since $\sin(\cdot)$ is bounded and continuous,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} h(t_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathsf{E}\sin(t_nX)=\mathsf{E}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(t_nX)=h(t)
$$
by the Bounded (Dominated) Convergence Theorem.